# Memory leak in Magento/Zend Framework

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

When running this simple script I get the output posted below. 
It makes me think that there is a memory leak in either my code or the Zend Framework/Magento stack. This issue occurs when iterating any kind of Magento collection.
Is there anything that I am missing or doing wrong?

Script:

```
$customersCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();

foreach($customersCollection as $customer) {
  $customer->load();
  $customer = null;
  echo memory_get_usage(). "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
102389104
102392920
...
110542528
110544744
```

Comment: This is another [reference](http://ringsdorff.net/2009/07/23/guest-post-fix-for-memory-leaks-in-magento) that I found. It looks like the problem resides on circular references.

Comment: @osondoar If you are using at least PHP 5.3 (which you should be by now) circular references will be caught by a Garbage Collector, although not immediately. However, see my answer for why your example will not free even non-circular references.

Comment: This is not appropriate usage of `load()` given Magento's ORM. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to leak memory in PHP's OOP implementation. See here for how this effects Magento: http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/garbage-collector/.  The `clearInstance` method (if implemented in the object, `$customer->clearInstance()`) can sometimes clear these references, but it's not always possible to control everything in a particular method call. For example, your call to `load` lacks an ID, which means Magento's trying to reload the object with a blank ID, which causes all sorts of weird instantiations and object cleanup, triggering the leak behavior.

Comment: @AlanStorm Once again, that article conflates PHP's memory manager (which *instantly* frees memory when a refcount reaches zero) with PHP 5.3+'s Garbage Collector (which *periodically* checks for circular references, whose refcount will never reach zero even though they are inaccessible).

Comment: Perhaps OP can specify which version of PHP he or she is running?

Comment: @AlanStorm The clearInstance method didn't realease any memory, at least in this case.

Comment: @benmarks I'm using PHP 5.3.15. The script is running on a cronjob for 150k+ customers, that's why memory leaks are an issue here. And yes, calling load in a loop is very very expensive, loading the collection beforehand makes more sense, but loading all the models at the same time might exhaust the memory. See my response for a different approach in case load() needs to be called for any reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that you are issuing fairly expensive queries with each iteration, when you could load the necessary data via the collection queries:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

will do the same, but all in one query. The caveat to this approach is that if there are any custom event observers for `customer_load_before` or `customer_load_after` events (there are no core observers for these), the observer will need to be run manually for each data model.

*Edit: credit to [osonodoar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026524/osondoar) for spotting an incorrect class reference (customer/customer vs customer/customer_collection)*

Answer (score 3):

The memory for an object (or other value) can only be freed when there are no references to it anywhere in the PHP process. In your case, the line `$customer = null` only decreases the number of references to that object by one, but it doesn't make it reach zero.

If you consider a simpler loop, this may become clearer:

```
$test = array('a' => 'hello');
foreach ( $test as $key => $value )
{
    // $value points at the same memory location as $test['a']
    // internally, that "zval" has a "refcount" of 2

    $value = null;
    // $value now points to a new memory location, but $test['a'] is unnaffected
    // the refcount drops to 1, but no memory is freed
}
```

Because you are using objects, there is an added twist - you can modify the object inside the loop without creating a new copy of it:

```
$test = array('a' => new __stdClass);
// $test['a'] is an empty object

foreach ( $test as $key => $value )
{
    // $value points at the same object as $test['a']
    // internally, that object has a "refcount" of 2

    $value->foo = "Some data that wasn't there before";
    // $value is still the same object as $test['a'], but that object now has extra data
    // This requires additional memory to store that object

    $value = null;
    // $value now points to a new memory location, but $test['a'] is unnaffected
    // the refcount drops to 1, but no memory is freed
}

// $test['a']->foo now contains the string assigned in the loop, consuming extra memory
```

In your case, the `->load()` method is presumably expanding the amount of data in each of the members of `$customersCollection` in turn, requiring more memory for each. Inspecting `$customersCollection` before and after the loop would probably confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when unsetting variables use unset($variable) instead of $variable=null.  It does essentially the same thing, but is much clearer as to your intent.

Second, PHP is meant to die - memory leaks aren't a huge issue, as a PHP request lasts maybe a few seconds, and then the process dies and all memory it was using is freed up for the next request.  Unless you are running into scaling issues, it's nothing to worry about.

Edit:  which isn't to say don't worry about the quality of your code, but for something like this, its most likely not worth the effort of trying to prevent it from happening unless it is causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The main problem here is that when iterating through 50000+ customers  memory allocation issues will arise. It you had your memory limit set to 512Mb for example, the script will crash

Answer (score 0):

Other way out to handle memory leak is that call exec within loop and let that exec function do the job part which results in memory leak.

So once it completes its part and terminates all memory leak within that exec will be released.

So with huge iterations this memory loss which keeps adding otherwise will be taken care.

Answer (score 0):

@benmarks response would be the right approach here, as calling load() within a loop is a very very expensive call.

Calling $customer->load() would allocate memory incrementally that would be referenced by $customersCollection, that memory won't be released until the end of the loop.

However, if load() needs to be called for any reason, the code below won't leak memory, as the GC releases all the memory allocated by the model in each iteration.

```
$customersCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();

foreach($customersCollection as $customer) {
    $customerCopy = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());

    //Call to $customerCopy methods

    echo memory_get_usage(). "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your code leaks for me. Adding `$customerCopy->clearInstance();` does the trick though.

Comment: Uhm...when I execute it looks like there is a leak BUT the GC is able to release memory every 5 seconds or so, keeping the memory consumption under a certain level. Different PHP/Magento configuration might explain why we get different results. Anyways, your response is the way to go, thanks!