# Memory usage increasing inside loop: are Magento functions the cause?

Tags: php, apache, oop, magento

My platform is PHP 5.2, Apache, Magento EE 1.9 and CentOS.

I have a pretty basic script which is fetching about 60,000 rows of data from an MS-SQL database using PHP's ms_sql() functions. The data is then processed a bit via data from Magento and finally written to a text file.

Really simple stuff...

```
$result = mssql_query($query);
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $member = $row; // Copied so I can modify it

    // Do some stuff with each row... e.g.:
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->loadByEmail($member["email"]);
    $customerId = $customer->getId();

    // Some more stuff like that...
    $ordersCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');

    // ...........

    // Some more stuff like that...
    $wishList = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer);

    // ...........

    // Write straight to a file
    fwrite($fp, implode("\t", $member) . "\r\n");

    // Probably not even necessary
    unset($member);
}
```

The problem is, the memory usage of my script increases with each iteration of the loop (about 10MB for every 300 rows), with a theoretical peak of about 2GB (though it hasn't got there yet).

I've taken great pains to ensure that I'm not leaving any data in memory. **No huge arrays are building up, no variables are being added to, everything is either `unset()` or directly overwritten with each iteration of the loop.**

So my question is: could the Magento functions be causing memory leaks?

And if so, how do I stop them from doing so?

**Ideally this script should be totally "passive": just grab the query results, modify them a bit (very temporary memory needed for this) then dump them straight to a file and destroy the memory. But this is not happening!**

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `SQL profiler` of SQL Server?

Comment: Also, which SQL Server driver you using? ODBC or native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes — PHP has a long history of non-ideal behavior when it comes to memory managment and code that pushes the edges of it's object oriented model.

You can try an [alternate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989594/memory-leak-in-magento-zend-framework) of querying for your data that wastes less memory, or you can [read up](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/garbage-collector/) on how the Magento core team deals with this same issue.

Comment: Thank you for that. I tried adding `->clearInstance()` to various of my objects but apparently none of the ones I'm using support it. For example, `$customer->clearInstance()` threw a fatal error. Is it only supported on product objects? 

Also I implemented this fix which seems to have helped. It's gone from +10MB increments to +3MB which is better: http://ringsdorff.net/2009/07/23/guest-post-fix-for-memory-leaks-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

**Exclude all `Mage::` from your code and just dump data to the file without processing.** And see what happens to the memory while doing this. Then start adding the `Mage::` functions back one by one and see when it breaks.

**This way you'll find the culprit.** Then you need to start digging into it's implementation and see what could go wrong. You could also consider doing the processing without relying on your `Mage::` calls. *Just write the plain code to deal with the data in self-contained functions/classes and compare how things turn out if you exclude `Mage::` entirely from the process.*

Comment: Indeed it seems that all of my Mage calls are the ones causing the memory leak. Apparently it's a known issue, which is very frustrating. I've yet to find a workaround which works for all the object types I'm using.

Comment: @WackGet If you can't implement your data modifiers without any `Mage::` dependency, I don't think there's anything you can do unless you track the bug and fix it yourself.